# On Dilworth's theorem

Tags: order-theory

Dilworth's Theorem on Posets states that if $P$ is a poset and $w(P)$ is the maximum cardinality of antichains in $P$ then there exist a decomposition of P of size $w(P)$.

The question is, why this theorem is not trivial?

Consider that there is a whole paper on Annals of Mathematics devoted to it:
Dilworth, Robert P. (1950), "A Decomposition Theorem for Partially Ordered Sets", Annals of Mathematics 51 (1): 161–166, doi:10.2307/1969503.

Best

f

Comment: If that were Dilworth’s theorem, it *would* be trivial, but in fact Dilworth’s theorem says that the maximum size of an antichain in $P$ equals the minimum size of a partition of $P$ **into chains**. It’s that last requirement that makes the result non-trivial.

Comment: @Brian, perhaps you'd like to make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 12):

If Dilworth’s theorem just said that every poset $P$ has a decomposition of size $w(P)$, where $w(P)$ is the maximum size of an antichain in $P$, it would indeed be trivial, but [Dilworth’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) is actually a much stronger statement. It says that if $w(P)$ is finite, then $w(P)$ is equal to the minimum size of any partition of $P$ **into chains**. The requirement that each member of the partition be a chain is what makes the theorem non-trivial. It isn’t enormously difficult $-$ there are nice short proofs by H. Tverberg (*On Dilworth’s decomposition theorem for partially ordered sets*, J. Combinatorial Theory 3 (1967), 305-306) and Fred Galvin (*A proof of Dilworth’s chain decomposition theorem*, Amer. Math. Monthly 101 (1994), 352-353) $-$ but it’s definitely not trivial.